# Как переделать выражение, чтобы оно заработало?

Tags: python

Создаются два объекта, первый и второй. Они создаются один раз. Надо сделать так, чтобы они получили ссылки друг на друга:

```
a = func(b)

b = func(а)
```

Понятное дело, возвращает ошибку, что `b` не определена.
Я знаю, есть хитрое решение этой проблемки, когда-то я его видел. 
Может быть, вы знаете? Если подскажете на Python, будет вообще отлично.

Comment: А что вы вообще пытаетесь сделать?

Comment: Если конкретнее, то создаются два объекта.Первый и второй.Они создаются один раз. Надо сделать так,что бы они получили ссылки друг на друга

Comment: В сторону: избегайте круговые ссылки, если нет хорошей причины их использовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно сначала создать оба объекта, а уже потом в каждом из объектов создать атрибут, который и будет ссылаться на второй объект.

Тогда каждый из объектов может обращаться к этому атрибуту, когда ему нужна будет ссылка на "напарника".

```
class func(object):

    def check(self):
        print self.link

a = func()
b = func()

a.link = b
b.link = a

print(a.check())
print(b)

# Выведет:
# <__main__.func object at 0x7fc9c3d3a050>
# <__main__.func object at 0x7fc9c3d3a050>

print(b.check())
print(a)

# Выведет
# <__main__.func object at 0x7fc9c3d29fd0>
# <__main__.func object at 0x7fc9c3d29fd0>
```

Как видите, каждый из объектов действительно теперь имеет доступ ко второму объекту.

А потом ещё можно будет сделать вот так :)

```
print(a.link.link.link.link.link.link.link.link.link)

# Выведет
# <__main__.func object at 0x7fc9c3d3a050>
```

Comment: Да, спасибо большое, все действительно может быть гораздо проще и работать так)

Answer (score 2):

Есть очень хитрый способ, инициализация переменных перед их использованием:

```
a = 0;
b = 0;
a = func(b);
b = func(а);
```

Profit!

Comment: к сожалению, я пробовал так, и так не сработает, синтаксически-то конечно, как вариант, но надо именно функции. передать.самого начала.Но все равно спасибо, что не прошли мимо.)

Comment: @АртемСуров нет, так нельзя делать, и так не нужно делать. у тебя где-то в логике ошибка

Comment: @АртемСуров, объясните, пожалуйста, что вам именно нужно сделать, иначе помочь вам трудновато.

Comment: @strangeqargo Да можно, как-то сделать.В питоне по крайней мере, но только с помощью очень хитровырученного костыля..